# Location / Geospatial Searching Possible?

Tags: google-search-appliance

My question is very straightforward, although I think the answer might not be :)

Can you do a geospatial search using Google Search Appliance?

If possible I would like to tag documents with geospatial metadata (latitude/longitude) and be able to run searches that return the closest documents by distance.  Think of the "store locator" scenario.

Would the GSA be a good fit for such a search?  We have one sitting around that is currently underutilized and I was hoping to use it for such a task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this should be possible.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/Google-Search-Appliance-Help/CpC-RDznBc4

essentially:

```
gas+station inmeta:latitude:30..50
```

To search in a radius you'll have to do the math yourself (ie, search within 30 mile radius of 30.0,-84.0)

Comment: OK, I see... But how do you order by distance.  This is something that for example Amazon CloudSearch can do: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-locations.html